# IBM Worklight: Failed to Upload Adapter in Worklight Console

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

I am trying to Upload Worklight Adapter in Worklight Console,but i am getting some error While Uploading adapter,

Error message

```
Failed to deploy adapter 'Sample.adapter'. : cvc-complex-type.3.2.2: Attribute 'platformVersion' is not allowed to appear in element 'ns2:adapter'.
```

Adapter.xml

```
<displayName>getRFQ</displayName>
<description>getRFQ</description>
<connectivity>
    <connectionPolicy xsi:type="http:HTTPConnectionPolicyType">
        <protocol>http</protocol>
        <domain>my server IP</domain>
        <port>8009</port>
        <!-- Following properties used by adapter's key manager for choosing specific certificate from key store  
        <sslCertificateAlias></sslCertificateAlias> 
        <sslCertificatePassword></sslCertificatePassword>
        -->     
    </connectionPolicy>
    <loadConstraints maxConcurrentConnectionsPerNode="2" />
</connectivity>

<procedure name="proc1"/>

<procedure name="proc2"/>

<procedure name="proc3"/>
```

How to Solve this issue.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Edit the question with your adapter XML and -impl.js files.

Comment: Please see the updated post. I can deploy adapter from eclipse in my local machine,but when i tried to deploy .adapter file from my another PC where worklight server is setup , i am getting this error.I tried deploying .apk file it works fine.

Answer (score 1):

This means you're using newer WL Studio and older WL server.